# Открытие и скрытие div при клике по ссылке

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте!

Помогите с задачей. В javascript не силен, а сделать надо.
Я делаю слайдер на базе map area. по клику на разные области у меня меняются изображения. 
Мне так же надо, что бы при клие на определенную area появлялся блок с описанием и когда я буду кликать на другую area первый блок закрывался, а нужный открывался.
Все перелопатил ничего не могу понять)))

Вот мой html:

```
<map name="slider">
    <area id="area1" name="redpepper" shape="poly" href="#" coords="570,132"/>
    <area id="area2" name="celery" shape="poly" href="#" coords="529,70"/>
</map>
```

и вот два скрытых блока

```
<div id="text-area1">Какой то текст</div>
<div id="text-area2">Какой то текст</div>
```

Я попробовал, некоторые варианты, которые советовали alvoro и KARTOH но не работает. Точнее работает, блок показывает, но прятать его при клике по другой area не хочет. Вот я попробовал код который KARTOH дал

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#area2').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        $('#text-area1').toggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

Этот код показывает скрытый блок, но когда я кликаю по другой area блок не скрывается.

Comment: html код приведите, пожалуйста

Comment: Очень не уверен, но попробуйте, для начала, так:

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#area2').click(function (event) {   /*кликаем */
            event.preventDefault()
            $('#text-area1').toggle("show");
        });
      });
    </script>

Comment: <pre>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#area2').click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault()
            // .toggle() будет переключать между display: hidden|block
            $('#text-area1').toggle();
        });
    });
</pre>

и не надо никакого css.

если надо чтоб изначально элемент был скрыт напишите

    <div style="display: hidden;">...</div>

или присвойте класс скрывающий элемент

Comment: либо 

    .toggle("slow");

либо

    .toggleClass('show');

:)

Comment: toggle устаревший метод... используйте $('#text-area1').show() для показа или $('#text-area1').hide() для скрытия, или вариант с анимцией, $('#text-area1').slideDown(500) для показа или $('#text-area1').slideUp(500) для скрытия.

Comment: @Nik555 event toggle устаревший, toggle - показать/скрыть  - нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скрытые блоки:

```
<div class="hidden" id="text-area1">Текст #1</div>
<div class="hidden" id="text-area2">Текст #2</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[shape=poly]').click(function () {
        $(".hidden").not($("#text-" + $(this).attr("id"))).hide();
        $("#text-" + $(this).attr("id")).toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Извините, я этот код вставил но не работает. Что я не правильно делаю? Я удалил старый скрипт, вставил этот, у скрытых блоков дописал класс hidden, в стилях у меня id area1,2 display: none. Не работает)) может это вы мне принцып тока показали и мне в коде надо что то подставить свое. Я не вижу в скрипте id area1, как скрипт определит что я жму на нее?

Comment: Я возможно вас не правильно понял. Я думал, что при нажатии на area1 и area2 показываются / скрываются блоки :) Их скрывать не нужно :) Для того, чтобы отследить нажатие я не использовал id блока, вместо этого использовал его значение shape.

Comment: Убрал display: none у блоков, не работает блиииин)))

Comment: @lookstuff, http://jsfiddle.net/aKfVx/ 
Использовал обычные ссылки вместо map area :)

Comment: Блин, класс!!! Решено, спасибо вам Jeix выручили просто капец. У меня вообщем bootstrap и там у него класс hidden скрыт что ли, я изменил класс в скрипте и все заработало еее!!!